# New facebook app cannot access comments but old one can

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two facebook apps. I am trying to access comments from posts using the graph api. Use an access_token from the old app I can access comments from a non-public post like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}/comments?access_token={access-token}

When I do this, I get json for all the comments on the post just as I would expect. But if I use an access token from my new app, when I make the same request I always get an empty data set like this:

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

If I make a request for a public post using the new app, I get results.  It is just the non-public posts that I get the empty dataset.  I checked and double-checked all the settings in both my new and old app, and the only difference I could find was that the old app has an alert that I need to fix "July 2013 Breaking Changes".
Could this be what makes the difference?  If I mark the old app as being fixed for "July 2013 Breaking Changes" will it stop working correctly too? Where else should I check?

Comment: DId you grant the two apps different sets of permissions?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions requested?

Comment: Under App > Settings > Permissions the permission look exactly the same.  There is no special permissions for either one.

Comment: Compare your user access token of both old/new app at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token. Look at the "Scopes" field.

Comment: Both of them look exactly the same.  

Scopes: read_stream

Comment: Are the posts gated in some way which prevents one user from seeing them?

Comment: No. I have decided to switch to using FQL instead of the graph API to see if that works correctly